# Parsing delimited data for specific instance of repeated line

Tags: c#, linq, parsing

I have an array of strings in the following format, where each string begins with a series of three characters indicating what type of data it contains. For example:

> ABC|.....
>   DEF|...
>   RHG|1........
>   RHG|2........
>   RHG|3........
>   XDF|......

I want to find any repeating lines (RHG in this example) and mark the last line with a special character:

> >RHG|3.........

What's the best way to do this? My current solution has a method to count the line headers and create a dictionary with the header counts.

```
protected Dictionary<string, int> CountHeaders(string[] lines)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> headerCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string s = lines[i].Substring(0, 3);

        int value;
        if (headerCounts.TryGetValue(s, out value))
            headerCounts[s]++;
        else
            headerCounts.Add(s, 1);
    }
    return headerCounts;
}
```

In the main parsing method, I select the lines that are repeated.

```
var repeats = CountHeaders(lines).Where(x => x.Value > 1).Select(x => x.Key);
foreach (string s in repeats)
{
    // Get last instance of line in lines and mark it
}
```

This is as far as I've gotten. I think I can do what I want with another LINQ query but I'm not too sure. Also, I can't help but feel that there's a more optimal solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ to achieve that.

Input string:

```
var input = @"ABC|.....
DEF|...
RHG|1........
RHG|2........
RHG|3........
XDF|......";
```

`LINQ` query:

```
var results = input.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine })
                   .GroupBy(x => x.Substring(0, 3))
                   .Select(g => g.ToList())
                   .SelectMany(g => g.Count > 1 ? g.Take(g.Count - 1).Concat(new[] { string.Format(">{0}", g[g.Count - 1]) }) : g)
                   .ToArray();
```

I used `Select(g => g.ToList())` projection to make `g.Count` *O(1)* operation in further query steps.

You can `Join` result array into one string using `String.Join` method:

```
var output = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, results);
```

Comment: +1, Thanks for notes, I don't see the point of making my answer the same as yours.

Comment: Wow thanks, didn't know I could do the entire thing in one LINQ query!

Comment: @Otaia LINQ is really powerful tool. You just have to know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could find repeating lines with a backreferencing regex. I wrote this hacky regex using your sample data and it matches the lines starting with a preceding 'tag', pipe seperated values.

```
^(?<Tag>.+)[|].+[\n\r](\k<Tag>[|].+[\n\r])+
```

The match range starts at the beginning of the first RHG line and selects up to the last RHG line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that includes the parsing and the counting in one Linq statement - feel free to break it up if you want to:

```
string[] data = new string[]
{
    "ABC|.....",
    "DEF|...",
    "RHG|1........",
    "RHG|2........",
    "RHG|3........",
    "XDF|......"
};

data.Select(d=> d.Split('|'))                     // split the strings
    .Select(d=> new { Key = d[0], Value = d[1] }) // select the key and value
    .GroupBy (d => d.Key)                         // group by the key
    .Where(g=>g.Count() > 1 )                     // find duplicates
    .Select(d => d.Skip(1))                       // select the repeating elements
    .SelectMany(g=>g)                             // flatten into a single list
    ;
```

This will give you a list of key/value pairs that are duplicates.  so with the sample data it will return

```
Key Value 
RHG 2........ 
RHG 3........
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "marking" the line, however...